# TFS 2010 CI Build with two UI projects

Tags: tfs

Ok, so I'm a total newbie to TFS and automated builds. I see how to set up a CI build in TFS pretty easily, along with the drop folder for output files. However, my solution has two UI projects in it. One is our main website, the other is a mobile site.

When developers check in, basically what I want to happen is for a CI build to fire, and then publish the "mobile" project to one server and the "website" project to another.

On a very high level, what steps do I need to take to make this happen? I'm not looking for a detailed explanation, I can Google individual things as needed I just want to know the basic process and what tools are leveraged to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have two different builds set up to fire on check in.

First, in your configuration manager create two new configurations.  One for the Mobile site and another for the main website.  The mobile site configuration shouldn't bother to build the website and vice versa.

Then create two builds.  For each build, set the 1.Required > Items to Build > Configurations to Build settings to pick the appropriate config to build.

Update your deployment locations as necessary.